# Нахождения простого числа C++

Tags: c++, циклы, простые-числа

Увидел алгоритм нахождения простого числа и не могу понять для чего нужно +1 ( i < sqrt(n) + 1 ), код и без нее нормально работает, или эта единица как-то оптимизирует код? На что она влияет?

```
int n;

for (i = 2; i < sqrt(n) + 1; ++i) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
    return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: надо же, чтобы цикл выполнился и для значения `sqrt(n)`. а раз там написано «строго меньше», то последняя итерация будет выполнена для числа `sqrt(n)-1`. можно не добавлять единицу, а убрать строгость из сравнения — заменить его на «меньше или равно».

Comment: плюс то, что может получиться что-нибудь вроде `sqrt(100000000)=9999.99997`, и прибавление единицы страхует от таких случаев

Comment: Резюмируя два комментария выше: надо `<= sqrt(n)+1` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это сделано для случая, если ваше число - квадрат простого числа. Тогда его первым и единственным нетривиальным делителем будет его корень. А если вы будете проходить циклом до тех пор, пока `i < sqrt(n)`, то вы до него не дойдёте и ваша функция скажет, что это число простое. Попробуйте запустить код без этой `+ 1` при `n = 25`.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы добавил, что этот код очень легко ускорить в 2 раза...

```
if (n%2==0) return false;
for (i = 3; i <= sqrt(n) + 1; i+=2) { // См. мой комментарий к вопросу
    if (n % i == 0) {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Еще условие завершения цикла можно записать как

```
for (i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2) {
```

Comment: Возможно Вы имели в виду второй return true. Но даже так алгоритм работает некорректно и неправильно определяет простые числа.

Comment: @Д-- https://ideone.com/mLl7QI — где?

Comment: `i <= sqrt(n) + 1`. Зачем `<=`? Не лучше ли `<`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Можно и так. Главное было в `i+=2`.